# Pass ViewPager with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I need help for how can I **implement** this if possible.

I want to use ListView to view a ViewPager and then go through them.

What I mean here is, when I click on ListView item0, thus open ViewPager item(in my case fragment)0 and so on. And if I opened ViewPager0 and swaps to 1,2,n So let the ListView know in which ViewPager I am (in order to avoid duplication or crashing).

Thank in advance.

Comment: So difficult to understand what you want, can you show some image or video?

Comment: @Hoàng Vū Anh - Very easy... Assume I have a custom ListView, so when I click on item number 0 from the ListView, open or put or throw a fragment to a ViewPager. And then swape through the ViewPager while changing the fragment.